Potential of Neutron scattering by crystal
According to Ashcroft and Mermin, the neutron-ion interaction is given by $V(r)=\frac{1}{V}\sum_Rv(r-r(R))=\sum_{k,R}v_ke^{ik.(r-r(R))}$. They mentioned that the range of $v$ is the order of $10^{-13}cm$, so its Fourier components will vary in the scale of $k\sim 10^{13}cm^{-1}$, and therefore essentially independent of $k$ for wave vectors of order $10^8cm^{-1}$ and $v_0$ is used as an approximation. Then they have argued that $v_0$ conventionally written in terms of scattering length $a$, defined so that the total cross section for scattering of a neutron by a single isolated ion is given in Born approximation by $4\pi a^2$, and thus written $V(r)=\frac{
2\pi \hbar^2 a}{M_nV}\sum_{k,R}e^{ik.(r-r(R))}$.
My confusion is about how $v(r-r(R))$ is a periodic function, so it can be written in the Fourier series. Isn't it a localized function? I hope there hides the importance of the value of $k$. Another confusion is from Born approximation how they obtained $v_0=\frac{2\pi \hbar^2a}{M_n}$?

Well, the crystal is periodic, so why would the potential not be?

$V(r)$ should be periodic, I am confused how $v(r-r(R))$ is periodic!

Consider that $V(r)$ is the potential of one lattice site. The potential at any given position is the sum across the potentials from all the lattice sites.
